# The maximum difference between the nth prime number and n x ln(n)

Tags: nt.number-theory

Is there an approximation for the maximum difference between P(n) and n x ln(n) as a function of n, where P(n) denotes the nth prime number?

In other words, given D(n) = Max(|P(n) - n x ln(n)|), is there a known formula for D(n)?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the first two pages of http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.5413

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several good inequalities for this difference, e.g.,
$$
n \log n + n(\log \log n -1)<P(n) < n \log n + n\log \log n
$$
for all $n\ge 6$, which can be derived from the prime number theorem.
Better estimates are given (among others) in the thesis of Dusart - see http://www.unilim.fr/laco/rapports/1998/R1998_06.pdf.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a similar approximation for P2(n) which denotes the nth number with exactly 2 prime factors? And more generally, for Pk(n)?